# What was the chest-level salute the Union soldiers used in Gettysburg?

Tags: gettysburg

What was the chest-level salute the Union soldiers used in Gettysburg?

I saw it a couple of times in this movie but I've never seen it elsewhere.

[image]

Comment: Is this the 1993 movie starring Jeff Daniels and Tom Berenger?

Comment: @steelerfan Yes it is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the correct position for a rifle salute. It is called a salute from right shoulder arms.

[image]

[image]

Sources: [image1](https://www.google.com/search?q=shoulder%20arms%20salute&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9u9DSxfnOAhVHpB4KHaWmDP8Q_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=915#tbm=isch&q=right%20shoulder%20arms%20salute&imgrc=zqmvnLEe7hE_OM%3A), [image2](https://www.google.com/search?q=rile%20salute&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX_u79xfnOAhVEKB4KHY1LAXkQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=915#imgrc=fn59VWLI5_uHGM%3A).

Comment: Years of ROTC has melded that unto my head.

Comment: @cde Not head, chest!  Bah-dah-dump.  ;)